# send <cr> to ipython in :term

Tags: terminal-buffer

When I am developing some python script, I regularly find myself running part of the code to see if it does what I want it to do. Currently I do this by copying the code that I want to run to the clipboard, alt-tabbing to the console and then `%paste`ing the code into ipython.

Of course this procedure is far from ideal, which is why I want to make use of the new `:term` and `term_sendkeys()`. I can send code to ipython using `term_sendkeys()`, but somehow I cannot get ipython to actually run the code. Below is a summary of my steps thus far:

First I start vim 8.1 using `vim -u NONE` in a normal command prompt on Windows 7. Then I run `:term` to create the terminal buffer. In this buffer I type `<c-w>:echo bufnr('%')<cr>` to find the number of the buffer and find that the number is `2`. Then I move to the text buffer and run two commands:

```
:call term_sendkeys(2, "ipython\<cr>")
:call term_sendkeys(2, "a=1\<cr>")
```

The first starts ipython as expected. The second enters `a=1` and a newline. However, when I type the same sequence of keys in ipython hitting enter actual executes the statement instead of starting a new line. I therefore believe that either vim is sending another key than I think it's sending or that ipython treats keys received in this way differently than keys received from the user directly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does term_feedkeys work for you? I’m not sure why this is happening though

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. `:call term_feedkeys(2, "a=1\<cr>")` results in an unknown function error and `:h term_feedkeys` says there is no help for this function.

Comment: Apologies, you need regular old `feedkeys` maybe

Comment: Do you mean something like `:buffer 2|feedkeys("a=1\<cr>", 'x')|buffer 1`? This produces the same result as `term_sendkeys`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with a shell (the example from `:h terminal-to-job`), regular python, or ipython. For me, all three of those do the correct thing. Note that the help says the job must be in the right state; perhaps your keys are being sent to ipython too early? Yet even for me sending the keys immediately works as expected

Comment: Thanks for your effort and interesting to hear that you cannot reproduce the issue. I'll need to reinstall my system shortly anyway, so in that case I won't spend too much time on this specific setup.